# React CSSTransition Help. Animation resetting. and not setting the enter class right away

Tags: css, reactjs, animation

my React code

```
    import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { CSSTransition } from 'react-transition-group'

import './styles.css';

const Fade = ({ children, ...props }) => (
  <CSSTransition
    {...props}
    timeout={600}
    classNames="slide-filter"
  >
    {children}
  </CSSTransition>
);

class FadeInAndOut extends React.Component {
    state = {
      show: false
    }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => this.setState((prevState) => {
          return { show: !prevState.show }
        })}>Toggle</button>
        <hr/>
      <Fade in={this.state.show}>
        <div className='greeting'>Hello world</div>
      </Fade>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

My CSS classes

```
.slide-filter-enter {
  transform: translateX(50%);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.6s ease-in;
  color:blue;
}
.slide-filter-enter-active {
  transform: translateX(0);
  color:red;
  opacity: 1;
}
.slide-filter-exit {
  transform: translateY(0);
  opacity: 1;
  color:red;
}
.slide-filter-exit-active {
  color:blue;
  transform: translateX(50%);
  transition: all 0.6s ease-in;
}
```

Ok I can't understand why this is not working. It just resets to its original state after animating.

Also why is the "enter" or "enter-active" class not applied the first time it is rendered on the screen?

Comment: You are required to post your code within your question, not a third party site. [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

So you want the position of the "Fade" component to stay at the end position of the animation? Forgive me if this is not the behavior you are looking for but try removing the `timeout={1000}` prop on line 10.

Comment: Thank you but I get this error if I do that: 
Failed prop type: The prop `timeout` is marked as required in `CSSTransition`, but its value is `undefined`.